# Laurent series in vicinity of a point

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this question:
Determine the Laurent series of function $f(z)$ in the vicinity of point $z_0=2$, where $f$ is the function

$$f(z)= \frac{\sin(z)}{z-2}.$$

If I use the Taylor series development for $\sin(z)$, I would have:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n} z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)! (z-2)}.$$

But that isn't Laurent Series in vicinity of point $z_0=2$, since we need have something like
$$f(z)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} {c_n} {(z-2)^n}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that$$\sin (z)=\sin(2+z-2)=\sin(2)\cos(z-2)+\cos(2)\sin(z-2)$$
and then use the expansions of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$.

Comment: Ok i found the solution $$f(z)=sen(2) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n} .{(z-2)}^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} + cos(2) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n}.{(z-2)}^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Thank you for that clue :)